# Multiple references on top of mathematical symbol in align environment

Tags: cross-referencing, align

I am trying to make a multiple reference inside an `align` environment. The reference should be on top of an `=` sign.

I thought of using `stackrel{}{}`, but the output doesn't seem much appealing!

My code is the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    P =\; & p_0(0) \times p_1(0) \times p_2(0) \times \cdots p_m(0) \times p_t\left(N=1\right)\\
      \stackrel{(\ref{eq:Poison0}), (\ref{eq:Poison1}), (\ref{eq:PoisonLeast1})}{=}\; & e^{-R(t_0)\delta t} \times e^{-R(t_1)\delta t} \times e^{-R(t_2)\delta t} \times \cdots\\
       \; &e^{-R(t_m)\delta t} \times R(t)\,\Delta t\,e^{-R\,\Delta t}\\
      =\, & exp\left\{{-\sum_{i=0}^m\left(R(t_i)\,\delta t\right)}\right\} \times R(t)\,\Delta t\,e^{-R\,\Delta t}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

A sample output can be seen below

[image]

Any idea on how to make it aesthetically better?

Comment: Don't do it?  \shortintertext{using (\ref{eq:Poison0}), (\ref{eq:Poison1}), (\ref{eq:PoisonLeast1})}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- this is opinion based question ...
- i would write this equation very different:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
P   & =  p_0(0) \times p_1(0) \times p_2(0) \times \cdots p_m(0) \times p_t\left(N=1\right)
\intertext{considering \eqref{eq:Poison0}, \eqref{eq:Poison1} 
           and \eqref{eq:PoisonLeast1} yields}% or any beter english phrase
    & = e^{-R(t_0)\delta t} \times e^{-R(t_1)\delta t} \times e^{-R(t_2)\delta t}
            \times \dotsm  \times e^{-R(t_m)\delta t} \times R(t) \Delta t\; e^{-R\,\Delta t}    \\
    & = \exp\left\{{-\sum_{i=0}^m\left(R(t_i)\,\delta t\right)}\right\} \times R(t)\Delta t\,e^{-R\,\Delta t}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a margin note with `\marginnote` and a compressed reference with `\Cref` etc, i.e. not printing it above some `=` character

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \label{eq:Poison0} \\
  \label{eq:Poison1} \\  
  \label{eq:PoisonLeast1} 
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
    P =\; & p_0(0) \times p_1(0) \times p_2(0) \times \cdots p_m(0) \times p_t\left(N=1\right)\\
    \marginnote{\Cref{eq:Poison0,eq:Poison1,eq:PoisonLeast1}}=\; & e^{-R(t_0)\delta t} \times e^{-R(t_1)\delta t} \times e^{-R(t_2)\delta t} \times \cdots\\
       \; &e^{-R(t_m)\delta t} \times R(t)\,\Delta t\,e^{-R\,\Delta t}\\
      =\, & exp\left\{{-\sum_{i=0}^m\left(R(t_i)\,\delta t\right)}\right\} \times R(t)\,\Delta t\,e^{-R\,\Delta t}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be to add the reference *after* the long line, flushright and in footnote size, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
     P & = p_0(0) \times p_1(0) \times p_2(0) \times \cdots p_m(0) \times p_t\left(N=1\right)\\
      & = e^{-R(t_0)\delta t} \times e^{-R(t_1)\delta t} \times e^{-R(t_2)\delta t} \times \cdots\times e^{-R(t_m)\delta t} \times R(t)\,\Delta t\,e^{-R\,\Delta t}\\
     \intertext[-1.25ex]{\raggedleft\footnotesize by \cref{eq:Poison0,eq:Poison1,eq:PoisonLeast1}}
    &= \exp\biggl\{{-\sum_{i=0}^m\bigl(R(t_i)\,\delta t\bigr)}\biggr\} \times R(t)\,\Delta t\,e^{-R\,\Delta t}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]